# moviepy add zoom-out animation to a ImagClip

Tags: python, animation, video, moviepy

Following is the ImageClip (red background) that is continually being fitted to the word. When the ImageClip jumps to the next word, I want to generate a small zoom-out effect.

```
    color_clip = ImageClip("background_image\\re_red_stone.png").set_start(highlight_word['start']).set_duration(highlight_duration)
    color_clip = color_clip.resize((width_word+padding_width, height_word+padding_height))
    color_clip = color_clip.set_opacity(.9)
```

Here you can see the normal transition - all words are filled correctly and completely by the ImageClip.

[image: simple transition from word to word without animation]

I wrote the following function and use it with resize

```
def resize_func(self, t):
    if t < self._word_duration / 3:
        new_width = self._word_width + 20 * t
        new_height = self._word_height + 20 * t 
        return new_width, new_height
    elif t < 2 * self._word_duration / 3:
        new_width = self._word_width + 20 * (self._word_duration / 3) + 10 * (t - self._word_duration / 3)
        new_height = self._word_height + 20 * (self._word_duration / 3) + 10 * (t - self._word_duration / 3)  # Zoom-in
        return new_width, new_height
    else:
        return self._word_width, self._word_height  # Stay zoomed-in.



color_clip = ImageClip("background_image\\re_red_stone.png").set_start(highlight_word['start']).set_duration(highlight_duration)
# color_clip = color_clip.resize((width_word+padding_width, height_word+padding_height))
color_clip = color_clip.resize(self.resize_func)
color_clip = color_clip.set_opacity(.9)
```

The following output is created, the animation effect works, however, the words (the width of the word are not transferred correctly)

[image]

why is that?
thanks in advance for your support